# jQuery.ajax response data giving null

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL database using jQuery and AJAX. I have written the query parameters in my add.php file. I would like to show the form data immediatly beneath the form.

jQuery:

```
jQuery("#addStockInForm").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  dataString = jQuery("#addStockInForm").serialize();
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add.php",
    data: dataString, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        //$("div#showinstant").html(data);
        alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

add.php file

```
require 'foo.config.php';
if(isset($_POST['addStockIn'])) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO stockin ( serialno, project_id, ...... etc. ) VALUES
(`:serialno, :project_id, ....... etc. )";
```

add-stockin.php file

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="addStockInForm" method="post">
.....
</form>
```

Comment: Your php code doesn't respond any data...?

Comment: Yes! it doesn't responding any data

Answer (score 0):

you should return the data from your php code back to your frontend

```
require 'foo.config.php';
if(isset($_POST['addStockIn'])) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO stockin ( serialno, project_id, ...... etc. ) VALUES
                                 (`:serialno, :project_id, ....... etc. )";
...
...
echo yourdata
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no return in add.php file. Though you are using dataType as 'json',
you should return the data in json format.
You should try something like this.

> add.php

```
require 'foo.config.php';
if(isset($_POST['addStockIn'])) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO stockin ( serialno, project_id, ...... etc. ) VALUES
(`:serialno, :project_id, ....... etc. )";
//extra code here
$output = array('res' => $data); //$data : form data to show in html file
$output = json_encode($output);
echo $output; exit;
```

> jQuery:

```
jQuery("#addStockInForm").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  dataString = jQuery("#addStockInForm").serialize();
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add.php",
    data: dataString, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        //$("div#showinstant").html(data);
        alert(data.res);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Now, Response like following- {"res":null}

Comment: It is too big code... How may i share with you? Okay, Let me try in googlecode

Comment: Add Stockin-
[link](https://wpcarsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/add-stockin.php)
Add PHP-
[link](https://wpcarsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/add.php)

Custom.js
[link](https://wpcarsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/custom.js)

@LX7

Comment: No luck yet... Firebug console report is following-

TypeError: data is null
[Break On This Error]  

$("div#showinstant").html(data.res);

Comment: Data is not inserting to database for sure... But, I can't figure out where is the problem... Can you give me few debugging way?

Answer (score 0):

Main problem was in elsewhere... The Problem was in isset funciton parameter

```
if(isset($_POST['addStockIn'])) {
}
```

I have changed this to

```
if(isset($_POST['serialno'])) {
}
```

And it's working fine!

@LX7 was helped me to think differently, thanks dude...